# Missing data when reading from Change Tracking Log on SQL Server 2017 database snapshot taken from always on replica

Tags: sql-server-2017, cdc, change-tracking

Wondering if anyone has come across this. We have a workaround for not being able to read change tracking (CT) logs from an always on replica, this error:

> Change tracking data must always be obtained from the primary replica. An attempt to access change data from a secondary replica will result in the following error:

> Msg 22117, Level 16, State 1, Line1

By creating a database snapshot from the read only replica the change log can be read and generally it works perfectly for incremental ETL. However, on occasion we have discovered missing rows from the destination and we need to reload the table.

My best guess is that Microsoft SQL Server don't support CT from read replicas because they're not always consistent but shouldn't it be? Can anyone advise what might be causing this?

Comment: What you're doing is not officially supported, CDC & CT are only supported on the primary - at least at present.

Comment: yeah... seems that way, however, i can't understand why we get missing rows when according to MS "The database snapshot is transactionally consistent with the source database as of the moment of the snapshot's creation." maybe we should log a ticket with MS.